# Angular 2 load module in modal popup

Tags: angular, popup, modal-dialog, loading, lazy-evaluation

I am using angular 2 with bootstrap. I have a requirement where - there is a dashboard page. Once user clicks on any link on dashboard page, new module is to shown on modal popup. How to achieve this. As the application size is big I would like to use angular lazy loading feature. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed. What does "new module" in  "new module is to shown on modal popup" mean. What about using the dialog component of https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap?

Comment: I think u need multiple router-outlet, u might hv to configure route for that modal and the components within

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs more details for a proper answer.

But from what I have gathered you want to load a modal with the content of another module.

This is easy to achieve:

Component A dashboard

Component B component to be shown on dashboard and has the selector componentB

Now define your modal code in your Component B, if you need data from component A just use @Input() in component B.

In component A  add your component selector in your html and use a button/link other element, to call the modal window.

Component A HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalWindowName">ok</a>
<componentB></componentB>
```

The above code will trigger the modal in component B with the name ModalWindowName.

You can communicate with the componentB using Input and Output to exchange values if needed.